# ordering field in nested abstract base model ignored?

Tags: django-models

I have a model which inherits from an abstract base model, which itself inherits from a further abstract base model, as in

```
class A(models.Model):
  class Meta:
    abstract = True
  timestamp = models.DateTimeField()

class B(A):
  class Meta:
    abstract = True

class C(B):
  # etc
```

I want all subclasses of A to be ordered by timestamp, so I added "ordering = ['timestamp']" to A.Meta.  However, that has no effect.  It works just fine if I add the ordering field to B.Meta.  I can't find any documentation that explains such a limitation - is that expected, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is almost 11 years old, but I found it while searching how to tackle this issue and it took me some time to find a solution.

As of Django 1.10 (at least), there is the possibility to inherit the `Meta class` of a parent `Abstract class` like this:

```
from django.db import models

class CommonInfo(models.Model):
    # ...
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        ordering = ['name']

class Student(CommonInfo):
    # ...
    class Meta(CommonInfo.Meta):
        db_table = 'student_info'
```

In this example, note that the `Meta` sub-class of `Student` inherits from `CommonInfo.Meta`. Cf. "meta inheritance" in [Django official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/models/#meta-inheritance).

At the end of the day, I believe this question is [more related to Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587653/inheritance-and-inner-classes-in-python#answer-5587711) than to Django itself. There is only one point you should pay attention to when using Django: database indexes and constraints must have a [unique name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/indexes#s-name). However this goes beyond the initial question.

Comment: Welcome to the Stack Overflow community, @gwaga. This is very good first answer, and provides the level of detail and explanation that we like to see around here. Keep up the good work.

Answer (score 1):

Inner classes are not inherited.

Comment: OK, is there any way to achieve the desired effect?

Comment: Not really. Define a separate class with the options, then bind to `Meta` during the class definition.