# Inheritance and inner classes in Python?

Tags: python, oop, class, inheritance, inner-classes

In the following code class `B` has inherited `yay` attribute from class `A`, I expected this. I'd also expect that inner class `B.Foo` behaves the same way but it doesn't.

How to make `B.Foo` to inherit `alice` attribute from class `A`? I need that the inner subclass `Foo` in `B` has both the attributes `alice` and `bob`.

Thanks.

```
>>> class A:
...     yay = True
...     class Foo:
...             alice = True
...
>>> class B(A):
...     nay = False
...     class Foo:
...             bob = False
>>> B.yay
True
>>> B.Foo.alice
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: class Foo has no attribute 'alice'
```

Comment: Why do you think you need inner classes? I've never seen a single situation where they would have occured to me as solution. Also, what's wrong with explicitly inheriting (as in `class Foo(A.Foo)`)?

Comment: You can always write equivalent solution without inner classes, but sometimes express code structure and class relations very well. Imagine a collection and an iterator - classical example of inner class usage (though more C++ oriented).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The reason why `B.Foo.alice` gave you an error is because there's no connection between `Foo` attribute of class `A` and `Foo` attribute of class `B`.

In `B`, attribute `Foo` has a class object value that completely replaces class object value inherited from `A`.

This should fix it:

```
class B(A):
    nay = False
    class Foo(A.Foo):
        bob = False
```

In general, it helps, at least for me, to think of a class body contents as a sequence of attributes with certain assigned values.

In case of class `B`, we have:

1. `yay` attribute that has value `True` inherited from A.
2. `nay` attribute that has value `False`.
3. `Foo` attribute that has class object.

Class methods are also attributes that have callable objects as values.

Answer (score 9):

Inheritance is a per-class thing. In your code class `B` inherits from class `A`, but just because both of them have inner class `Foo` doesn't tell us anything about their inheritance.

If you want `B.Foo` to have the attributes from `A.Foo`, you need to make `B.Foo` inherit from `A.Foo`:

```
class B(A):
    class Foo(A.Foo):
        bob = False
```

Comment: In fact, Python's last Zen Koan specifically says "Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!". B.Foo is then obviously different from A.Foo.

Comment: In Python 3, `class Foo: pass` is the correct syntax for new style (the only style) classes it has. See: http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/reference/compound_stmts.html#class-definitions

Comment: @pavel You're right. So since the OP didn't say which version is using I will remove section about classes.

Answer (score 1):

`Foo` is it's own class. It does not inherit from `A`. Because of this, it does not have any fields of `A`. The fact that is nested in a subclass of `A` does not change anything.