# Python metaclass (abc module) inheritance with nested classes

Tags: python, inheritance, metaclass, abc

I've written a Python 3 metaclass containing a nested metaclass (with abc), like:

```
class A_M(object, metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    class A_nested_M(object, metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
        def ... # some methods
```

Now, implementing like

```
class A(A_M):
     class A_nested(A_nested_M):
        def ...
```

doesn't work. So, did i miss something about usage of metaclasses or is this type of implementation with nested metaclasses not working at all?

Comment: Does it work if you inherit like this ``class A_nested(A_M.A_nested_M):``?

Comment: `A_nested_M` is 'hidden' in `A_M`. Maybe you can access it with `class A_nested(A_M.A_nested_M): ...`?

Comment: Thanks! Somehow, this works with normal nested classes, but not metaclasses. As i said, did i miss something about the metaclass concept?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? These snippets suggest some attempt that have no practical use at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing: 
Nesting class declarations is of near no use for anything in Python. Unless you are using the nested class hierarchy itself as a hard-coded namespace to keep attributes, you probably are doing the wrong thing already.

You did not tell what your (actual) problem is and what you are trying to achieve there, nor why you are using the ABCmeta metaclass. So it is hard to suggest any actually useful answers - but we can try clarifying some things:

First: you are not writting a metaclass, as you suggest in the text "I've written a Python 3 metaclass containing a nested metaclass..." - you are creating ordinary classes that *have* the ABCmeta as its metaclass. But you are not creating new metaclasses - You would if you were inheriting from `type` or from `ABCMeta` itself - them your new class would be used in the `metaclass=` parameter of subsequent (ordinary) classes. That is not the case.

Now, second, everything that is defined inside the body of your outermost `A_M` class will be only "visible" as attributes of `A_M` itself. That is the source of your error - when you try to inherit from `A_nested_M` you should actually write:

```
class A_M(object, metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    class A_nested_M(object, metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
        def ... # some methods


class A(A_M):
     class A_nested(A_M.A_nested_M):
        def ...
```

See - `A_M.A_nested_M` will make Python find the superclass for `A_nested`: there is no reference in the local or global namespaces for `A_nested_M` as it only exists as an attribute of `A_M` outside the body of the `class A_M...` statement.

That said, this is still useless. If you want to have *instances* of `A_nested` referenced by instances of `A` class, you have to create these instances inside `A.__init__()` call - at which point it makes no difference if `A_nested` is declared inside a class body or at the module level:

```
class A_M(object, metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    pass

class A_nested_M(object, metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    def ... # some methods

class A_nested(A_nested_M):
   ...

class A(A_M):
    def __init__(self):
         self.nested = A_nested()
```

Now, that can be of some use. You can also declare the classes actually nested, but the only way they can be useful is by creating instances of them anyway. And unlike nested functions, nested classes do not have access to attributes or variables declared on the "nesting" class namespace (but for referring to them by their qualified name. I.e. in your example, if the `A` class would contain a `b` classmethod,  a method inside `A_nested` that would call this method would have to call `A.b()`, not `b()`)

Answer (score 1):

You should implement your class like this:

```
class A(A_M):
     class A_nested(A_M.A_nested_M):
        def ...
```

Because `A_nested_M` is an inner class, you should access it just like you would access any of the class attributes, i.e. `A_M.A_nested_M`. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5587711/5132608).

Comment: This throws me an `AttributeError: module 'A_M' has no attribute 'A_nested_M' `.

Comment: @norb I'm not sure why it doesn't work with metaclasses. This will probably cost me some downvotes, but I will leave this answer for the time being, maybe someone knows the explanation why this doesn't work with metaclasses.